# failed to open stream: Permission denied for php move upload file

Tags: php, html

i am trying to create an upload functionality in the website using php, but i am getting the permission denied error, i changed the user permissions of the folder still the same error .is there any alternative to move_uploaded_file in php?

here is my code :

```
             <?php

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
   // $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";    
     }

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }
$uploadfile="new/uploads";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$uploadfile.$file_name);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

html code :
 <form action="upload1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

you have any toughts,pls help me out

Comment: Fun-fact: someone could upload a file with a fake file-name like `../../../../../../../../` and place files arbitrarily in your filesystem.

Comment: os you are using ? brief your path!

Comment: try to change this `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$uploadfile.$file_name);` to `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$uploadfile."/".$file_name);` and also as @Dai said you need to work on securing your upload.

Comment: i didn't get the error using "/"  but the file was not uploaded @user969068